# Flutter Responsive Grid with Cards (screenshots)

Tags: flutter, grid, responsive, screenshot, orientation

I am very new to flutter and modern programming languages at all. At the moment I am working together with someone in order to create an app.
We are having problems with the layout of the grid and cards with different screen sizes and orientations.

[Vertical Screen Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U924x.png)

[Horizontal Screen Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfwTO.png)

As you can see, the cards are messed up as soon as the screen width is too high. I don't have access to the source code right now, as the person programming it, is not available at the moment.
I read a lot about different techniques to build a card grid like that in a responsive way.

My guess the problem is, that the cards are not in containers with a fixed size. If they were, the pictures / buttons and texts inside that container would always look the same. Is that assumption correct?
Then my other idea was to use ResponsiveGridListBuilder to solve the problem that too few cards are shown in horizontal mode.
But as I said ... I am a newbie in flutter, so if any of you could make suggestions, I would be happy!
If possible, some code as an example would also help a bunch.

So far the programmer only tried different calculations of the cards in comparison to the screensize, but this didn't help as you can see.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you use `Wrap` to fill the `Row` even in horizontal or vertical screens. but if i was in your shoes i would develop the items that are suitable and has const size for vertical and horizontal sizes, and let them to fill theirselves in the row depends on the width screen size that it has.
if you didn't understand what i mean i can explain it more my friend :)
happy coding...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
Do you mean you would basically define the different items with hardcoded values, for example a width of 400 and a specific spacing between the items and then check how many fit into the screen and create rows / columns accordingly?

Comment: I mean, create an item that has static size(even it rotates) and use Wrap widget. using wrap will fill that item according the size of that row or a column for example not just 3 items in one row. please search about Wrap and how it works and create that item with sizes that you rotate the screen it does not change the schema. and let it fill the items itself. if you had any question or did not find out, we can connect on google meet and i can explain it more.

Comment: Thanks, that is already a big help. I'll research about it! What you describe (the item rotates with identical size) is exactly what I am looking for.